# How are the tolerances evaluated in fmincon? specific/complete mathematical formulations needed.

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently studying the stopping criteria about fmincon using different algorithms and I'm wondering how are the tolerances are actually evaluated and compared in the built-in function fmincon. Especially I want to know what the units of the tolerances are compared to the objective function and variable. For instance, if the unit of the objective function or the cost is in dollars and the unit of the variables(X) is in km/h for every 30 mins, then what's the unit of the tolerances after the calculation. 
I already checked all these links:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html
and the webpages about fmincon and exit messages explanations.

The definition shown on the webpage still seem a little vague to me. For example, 
what type of norm did Matlab use in fmincon to compute |ceq(x)|, and what units does it return compare to the cost function and variables, km/h? (km/h)^2?. And I have same questions about |f(xi)-f(xi+1)| and TolFun. I was wondering if I can get any detailed mathematics formulation used for the calculation of the parameters and the tolerances related to the stopping criteria. For instance, in "fmincon" code and under interior point method, I found something such as 
if optimError

It would be great if I can get help with this.Appreciated!

Comment: I assume that you've looked at the source code? Type `edit fmincon` in your Command Window. This question would probably be best ask on the [MathWorks forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I can get the code for function fmincon and nlconst (for algorithm Active Set) , however, I still can't get information about the functions barrier() and sqpLineSearch(), which are called in fmincon for algorithms interior point and sqp. They're probably not meant to be provided to matlab users I guess.

Comment: Yes, both of those appear to be `pcode` content-obscured functions. If you really need to know specific details, I'd recommend [filing a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs) with The MathWorks to see if they're willing to share anything. It won't be the same exact algorithms, but you can try looking at the code in open source alternatives – see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49926/2278029).